# KitKat exploit for reading fils in /data

Tags: security, data-recovery

My Motoroa Droid MAXX  is running a version of Android that has no rooting method. All I want to do is read Chrome's backed up file of tge list of open tabs. Does Android 4.4.4 have any known exploitthatcan get me read access to the files in `/data`? Remember, this doesn't need to be a vulnerability through which I can gain root access.

Comment: The "Dirty Cow" exploit will most likely work on a device that runs a Android version before Oct 2016.

Comment: @Robert My device's system partition is mounted read-only.

Comment: Yes the system partition is by default read-only. I don't see any relationship between your question and that fact.

Comment: @Robert I'm also only looking for a way to read files.